# Too many indentation levels in on_press (Button)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I need to put `if` block into `on_press` event but my compiler don't let this code go. It says that i had too many indentation levels. I'm missing something? Am I doing right? How does this work? If it`s a bug, how can I avoid it? This error appears for me both on 1.9.1 and 1.9.0 Kivy.

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string('''
#:set some_data 'text'
#:set Condition True

<MyClass>:
    text: 'Some text'
    on_press: 
        if Condition: 
            root.doSomething()
            root.DoSomething(some_data)
''')

class MyClass(Button):
    def DoSomething(*args):
        pass #not actually doing anything

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyClass()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**kv output**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "file.py", line 15, in <module>
 ''')
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1889, in load_string
 parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1264, in __init__
 self.parse(content)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1366, in parse
 objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1540, in parse_level
 'Invalid indentation (too many levels)')
 kivy.lang.ParserException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 8:
 ...
       7:       on_press:
       8:               if Condition:
 >>    9:                       root.doSomething()
      10:                       root.DoSomething(some_data)
 ...
 Invalid indentation (too many levels)
```

This works if I place `if` right on the same line:

```
on_press: if Condition: DoSomething()
```

but I can only use one action after `if` this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because it's not implemented. At least not in the way you think it'd work. It also indicates that you should move the logic directly to Python. Too much blocks of code, mainly stuff like this in `kv` file will become mess. That seems like a good way for the future code, otherwise you'd need only `kv` file and that's not optimal for profiling, printing and other kinky methods you'd do to a `.py` file while coding.

`.kv` files are mostly used for layout design and a little bit of logic that would be just annoying to write in python e.g. with partials, methods with argument (un)packing and so on. I think the language still needs a little bit of work and this could be considered a bug (if the language supports such blocks), but you can work with it quite good even without whole `if-else` block.

E.g. like this:

```
Button:
    text: 'a'
    on_press:
        if self.text == 'a': print 'It is A!'; print 'Sure it is!'
        else: print 'No.'
```

Good old `;` comes to the rescue and you're free to put there how many lines you want.